# Gradle Docker plugin broken pipe on osx

Tags: macos, gradle, docker, docker-machine, broken-pipe

Hi I try to use this awesome Gradle plugin: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin 
I use the following URL obtained from my docker-machine / kitematic installation on osx:

```
docker-machine url default
tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

However using:

```
url = "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
```

results in the error:

`org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: tcp protocol is not supported`

When I change the `tcp` to `http`I get a different error:

```
INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[pool-4-thread-1] ERROR com.github.dockerjava.core.async.ResultCallbackTemplate - Error during callback
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
```

in case the  `gradle dockerBuildImage` task is run.
But manually building the Dockerfile created by gradle works without any problems.

The following code can be used to replicate the problem. https://github.com/geoHeil/lab04/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-machine enables TLS by default. I Switching to the `TLS`mode should be a good solution:

```
url = 'https://192.168.59.103:2376'
certPath = new File(System.properties['user.home'], '.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm')
```